Bitbucket trigger in Jenkins declarative pipeline
I'd like to trigger a Jenkins pipeline after a PR is created (and edited) in Bitbucket.
My pipeline is a declarative pipeline script (groovy).
How to define the trigger(s)?
Here is an idea, but it doesn't work:
pipeline {
  triggers {
    bitBucketTrigger([
      pullRequestServerCreatedAction(allowedBranches: 'origin/(.*)', isToApprove: true),
      pullRequestServerUpdatedAction(allowedBranches: 'origin/(.*)', isToApprove: true)
    ])
  }
  stages {
    ...
  }
}



Install the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin
Create a Multibranch Pipeline Job: Configure your job with the necessary details, including the Bitbucket repository.
Configure Bitbucket Webhook:


In your Bitbucket repository, go to Settings > Webhooks.
Add a new webhook with the URL: http://<your-jenkins-url>/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify.


Set Up Branch Sources:


In your Multibranch Pipeline job configuration, under Branch Sources, add your Bitbucket repository.
Ensure the Build Strategies include PRs. You can use the Basic Branch Build Strategies Plugin to configure this.


Configure PR Build Trigger:


In the Branch Sources section, configure the Bitbucket plugin.
Ensure the Discover pull requests from origin and Discover pull requests from forks options are enabled.


Create a PR in your Bitbucket repository to test if the Jenkins job is triggered automatically.


Thanks! But why can I not use the "Bitbucket Push and Pull Request" Plugin?

Bitbucket Branch Source plugin allows use of Bitbucket Cloud and Server as a multi-branch project source in two different ways:
Single repository source: automatic creation of jobs for branches and pull requests in a specific repository.
